# Ideals: If $\langle f_1,f_2 \rangle = \langle g_1,g_2 \rangle$, then $\langle f_1-\lambda,f_2-\mu \rangle = \langle g_1-\delta,g_2-\epsilon \rangle$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, ideals

The following question appears in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4760401/if-langle-f-1-f-2-rangle-langle-g-1-g-2-rangle-then-langle-f-1-lambd) without answers.

Let $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2 \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]-\mathbb{C}$.

Assume that $\langle f_1,f_2 \rangle = \langle g_1,g_2 \rangle \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$,
where $\langle u,v \rangle$ denotes the ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ generated by $u$ and $v$.

**Claim:**
Given $\lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}$, $(\lambda,\mu) \neq (0,0)$ (but one of $\{\lambda,\mu\}$ can be zero),
there exist $\delta,\epsilon \in \mathbb{C}$
such that
$\langle f_1-\lambda,f_2-\mu \rangle = \langle g_1-\delta,g_2-\epsilon \rangle$.

Notice that in the claim, necessarily $(\delta,\epsilon) \neq (0,0)$; otherwise, $\delta=\epsilon=0$, so
$I:= \langle f_1-\lambda,f_2-\mu \rangle = \langle g_1,g_2\rangle= 
\langle f_1,f_2 \rangle$ and then $I=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ since w.l.o.g. $\lambda \neq 0$, hence
$\lambda=f_1-(f_1-\lambda) \in I$.

> **Question 1:**
> Is the claim true when $\langle f_1,f_2 \rangle = \langle g_1,g_2 \rangle$ is a maximal ideal?

> **Question 2:**
> Is the claim true when $\langle f_1,f_2 \rangle = \langle g_1,g_2 \rangle$ is a finite intersection of maximal ideals?

> **Question 3:**
> Are the following two sets equal?
> $\{ \langle f_1-\lambda,f_2-\mu \rangle \}_{ \lambda,\mu \in \mathbb{C}}$ and $\{ \langle g_1-\delta,g_2-\epsilon \rangle \}_{ \delta,\epsilon \in \mathbb{C}}$.

**Examples:**

**(i)** $f_1=x+y,f_2=x-y,g_1=x,g_2=y$, namely,
$\langle x+y,x-y \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle$.
If we choose $\lambda=1,\mu=2$,
then we can take $\delta=\frac{3}{2}, \epsilon=-\frac{1}{2}$ and get $\langle x+y-1,x-y-2 \rangle = \langle x-\frac{3}{2},y+\frac{1}{2} \rangle$.

- This example shows that it is generally *not* true that
  $\langle f_1-\lambda,f_2-\mu \rangle = \langle g_1-\lambda,g_2-\mu \rangle$.
- At least for linear $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2$, there exist $\delta,\epsilon$ such that
  $\langle f_1-\lambda,f_2-\mu \rangle = \langle g_1-\delta,g_2-\epsilon \rangle$.
  Linear means of the form $ax+by+c$, for some $a,b,c \in \mathbb{C}$.

**(ii)** $f_1=x,f_2=y+x^2+5x+3,g_1=x,g_2=y+3$, namely,
$\langle x,y+x^2+5x+3 \rangle = \langle x,y+3 \rangle$. If we choose $\lambda=0,\mu=3$, then we can take $\delta=0,\epsilon=3$ and get
$\langle x,y+x^2+5x \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle$.

- In this particular example $(\lambda,\mu)=(\delta,\epsilon)=(0,3)$.
- It seems that at least for triangular/linear $f_1,f_2,g_1,g_2$, there exist $\delta,\epsilon$ such that
  $\langle f_1-\lambda,f_2-\mu \rangle = \langle g_1-\delta,g_2-\epsilon \rangle$.
  Triangular means of the form $ax+F(y)$ or $by+G(x)$, for some $a,b \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$, $F(y) \in \mathbb{C}[y]$, $G(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

**Remarks:**

**(i)** Every finite intersection of maximal ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is (a radical ideal) that can be generated by two elements, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4399584/generators-of-a-finite-intersection-of-maximal-ideals?noredirect=1&lq=1).

**(ii)** For the general case where $\langle f_1,f_2 \rangle = \langle g_1,g_2 \rangle \subsetneq \mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is not even radical, perhaps it is interesting to consider $f_1=x+y,f_2=xy,g_1=x+y,g_2=x^2+y^2$.

$\langle x+y,xy \rangle \subsetneq \langle x,y \rangle$ and it is not a radical ideal, since $x^2 \in \langle x+y,xy \rangle$, but $x \notin 
\langle x+y,xy \rangle$. (Indeed, $x^2=(x+y)x-xy$).

Thank you very much!

Comment: In the title I thought $\langle f_1,f_2 \rangle$ was some sort of inner product.  But now I guess it means the ideal generated by $\{f_1,f_2\}$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, thank you for your comment. I apologize. Should I change it to $(,)$? Or write it is an ideal?

Comment: No need to change.  Merely state the definition at the beginning.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar, thank you, I will edit it now. I will try to make the title more clear and state the definition at the beginning.

Comment: Compare $\langle x,y\rangle$ with $\langle x(1-xy),y\rangle$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your questions is no. The ideals $\langle x, y(1-xy) \rangle$ and $\langle x, y \rangle$ are equal, and maximal; but

$$ \langle x-\lambda, y(1-xy)\rangle \neq \langle x-\delta, y-\epsilon \rangle$$

for any $\lambda,\delta,\epsilon \in \mathbb{C}$, $\lambda \neq 0$. (In the notation of your questions, $\mu=0$.)

A related example is $\langle x, 1-xy\rangle = \langle 1 \rangle$, but $\langle x-\lambda, 1-xy \rangle \neq \langle 1 \rangle$ for nonzero $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very nice.